# Accessing WCF in http from a CRM page in https

Tags: wcf, cross-domain, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a WCF service which is running on my local machine and is having an http url.
I have a CRM which has a ribbon button which calls a jQuery function which invokes function inside my WCF service.
In development machine, my WCF and CRM were having http.

In production, the WCF continues to be in http but CRM is having https..

is this the reason that calls from my CRM's button click do not land in my WCF service?

In Production, my CRM server and my client machine are both on the same domain.

Please suggest a solution to this.

Comment: The WCF Service in the client machine / local machine is hosted in Windows Service

Comment: i also tried hosting this WCF service inside IIS on my local machine in http as well as https.. but i get the same exception

Comment: i tried hosting this WCF service inside IIS on CRM server and it seems to be working with https.. however, it continues to give the same error when hosted in http

the error that javascript gives me is [object Error]

Comment: When i use datatype=jsonp while making the ajax request, it still hits my error function..
however, in the status it shows as 200 and the message it shows as "success"

Comment: ok, i've concluded that this WCF call is workin if my CRM and the WCF are  on the same link..
so if i open CRM using NLB link (eg: https://crm.myorg.com/main.aspx) and access my service using same NLB link (https://crm.myorg.com/MyService), it wrks fine
similarly, if i open CRM using specific server link (eg: https://server1/main.aspx) and access my service using same server link (https://server1/Myservice), it wrks fine..

however, if i provide server URL for service and access CRM using NLB or vice-versa, it gives me the [Object Error]

Comment: i've been using $.support.cors = true

Comment: still strugglin.. only a service that is hosted on the same path, port and protocol as CRM is getting hit..

as a wrkaround,. hosting this service in multiple folders under the same address.. so each client (which was earlier supposed to connect to his own machine's service) will now connect to service hosted in one of the folders.. (HARDCODING)